# .equals() on a PriorityQueue returns unexpected results

Tags: java, equals, priority-queue, hashcode

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question (especially for someone who has developed in java for over 4 years) or if it has been answered (I've searched stack overflow and despite the simplicity of the problem, I couldn't find a duplicate) but I created two priority queues and wanted to check if they contain exactly the same elements in exactly the same order.  However, I was returned false when I called .equals() on two seemingly equal priority queues. I would expect this much from a direct comparison (==) but not from the .equals() method.  I've looked on java docs and they don't provide an explanation for this behavior.

To test out this behavior I ran the following code segments:

```
PriorityQueue<Character> window = new PriorityQueue<>();
PriorityQueue<Character> base = new PriorityQueue<>();
System.out.println(window.equals(base));
System.out.println(base.equals(base));
window.offer('a');
window.offer('b');
base.offer('a');
base.offer('b');
System.out.println(window.equals(base));
```

And the output was:

```
false
true
false
```

However, I expected:

```
true
true
true
```

I have overridden equals methods before, so if this is something I must do, I can handle that, but I was just very taken aback by the results.  I know I could convert my PriorityQueue to a string or an array, and then compare them, but that defeats the entire point of using a PriorityQueue (not to mention all the excess space it will take up).

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* you need to check two priority queues for equality? I guess I can see wanting to know if they contain the same items, but order is irrelevant because the priority queue will always return them in the proper order. I'm not saying that you *don't* need to do this, just that in my experience having to compare two priority queues for equality is not exactly a common requirement.

Comment: It was a pretty niche reason, and after a while, I found a better solution that didn't involve priority queues. Anyways, I was solving a kattis problem that involved checking permutations. For every section of numbers, I would add them to a priority queue (sliding window style) and calculate the base permutations (ascending order priority queue).  Since I was doing this sliding window style, I liked the idea of priority queues. I would then check with a specific number of other priority queues to see if I had already encountered the base permutation. I came here after .equals() failed me :(.

Comment: It might not have actually been a kattis problem (can't remember which site I saw it on), but it was in the same format...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Javadoc for `PriorityQueue` shows that neither `PriorityQueue` nor any of its superclasses provide an implementation of `equals()`, and thus it inherits the one from `Object`.

Thus you get only reference equality, not contents equality.

As to implementing your own `equals()`, this looks complex for several reasons:

- `Queue` implements `iterable()` but the iterator is not guaranteed to return items in any particular order.  So `equals()` must deal with order differences in otherwise identical queues.
- You could add the items to a `Set`, but if you have items that are duplicates (according to *their* `equals()`) then you need to handle that.

This is why the Javadoc contains the statement:

> The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` and the `Spliterator` provided in method `spliterator()` are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

Comment: Thanks, given PriorityQueue does not have a content equality check, how should I got about comparing PriorityQueues?

Comment: You'll have to provide your own equality-testing method.

Comment: I figure as much and even suggested that as a possible solution to my question. However, due to the nature of PriorityQueues, what would be the best way to do this? It seems most ways would involve substantial tradeoffs (converting to an array or string would result in a lot of extra space which is then thrown own in the next garbage collection cycle, which is quite wasteful, and obviously I can't just do a while loop and compare each element after .poll() as that would destroy the queue.

Comment: Also, should I edit my question to make clear that I would like suggestions for possible solutions? or is that unnecessary?

Comment: THANKS! while it is disappointing to learn that there is no simple/elegant answer to this problem, I appreciate your help.  Perhaps the better solution would be to scrap the idea of a PriorityQueue and use a TreeMap instead, with each key-value pair in the map representing the count of a particular value.  Since it is a map, it has a very straightforward .equals() method.  For now though, I'll accept your answer!

Comment: FWIW, the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) explicitly states that PriorityQueue inherits equals() from Object. Scroll down to 'Methods Inherited...'.